# Windows 10 IoT and Adafruit M0 BLE comminication

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uwp, windows-iot-core-10, adafruit

I'm running windows 10 IoT (v14342) on raspberry pi 3 and trying to communicate with Adafruit M0 BLE feather module. After pairing, I'm able to write and receive messages from it and if feather module temporarily loses power, it seems like windows 10 IoT is not able to write anything to it. 
My program writes notification characteristics to the feather module and it gives the following exception:

> There is no user session key for the specified logon session.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070572)

Does it mean that it is losing pairing information? If so, I see that W10 and feather get connected. (Blue LED on the feather side lights up)

I'm not sure which side the problem exists. Also, how do I debug Bluetooth services on windows 10 side.

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Another solution is to use the [in-app pairing APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt168401.aspx) and have the `DevicePairingProtectionLevel` be `None`. Then the system does not need the bonding information to communicate with the paired peripheral. In this case, your in-app pairing code may look like `var result = await someDevice.Pairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.None);`